# Unique filenames from Unix to Windows

Tags: c#, string, case-sensitive

I need to move periodically some files by ftp from a Unix system to a Windows system: "123_abc.pdf", "123_Abc.pdf", "345_cde.pdf".

I need to use these filenames in a Windows application in C# keeping differences of casing.

I prefer not to use a metadata file so my solution is to append to string a unique number that represents the second part (after undescore):

- 123_abc.pdf  -> 123_ABC_999999999.pdf   (999999999 is only for example)
- 123_Abc.pdf  -> 123_ABC_000000000.pdf
- 345_cde.pdf  -> 345_CDE_123456789.pdf

then move them by ftp and try to rebuild original name to store it (the name) in a database.

How can I generate that number? The function must be reversible (so no `GetHashCode()`) so in a second moment I can:

1. Compare the `f-1(999999999) == ABC`;
2. Rebuild original string appending the first part of the string to the f-1 result: `"123_" + "abc" + ".pdf"` ;

My first idea:

```
MD5 md5Hasher = MD5.Create();
var hashed = md5Hasher.ComputeHash(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("ABC"));
var ivalue = BitConverter.ToInt32(hashed, 0);
```

EDIT: I won't use case sensitive folders in Windows.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

As explained in the comments, one way of making sure file names that only differ by case are moved to Windows properly is to represent each char in the file name as their hex value:

```
// Since .NET uses unicode chars, the hex representation
// for each char will have 4 digits
// The below has no error handling, you should add that

public static string CharToHex(char c)
{
    string lookup = "0123456789abcdef";
    int n = (int)c;
    char[] hex = new [] {
        lookup[(n >> 24) & 0xf],
        lookup[(n >> 16) & 0xf],
        lookup[(n >> 8) & 0xf],
        lookup[n & 0xf]
    };
    return new string(hex);
}
```

The reverse is slightly more complicated but should not be too difficult to figure out.

If anyone knows any built-in methods in the .NET framework, please feel free to share.

Comment: Thanks. Can you add the code to use this method and show me how "Abc" is different from "abc"?

Comment: I found: `var result = string.Join("", "Abc".Select(c => ((int)c).ToString("X2")));`